# using shell operators with Scala process builder?

Tags: bash, scala, awk

I'm trying to run a set of shell commands using the Scala process builder. In Scala, I run the process builder like this:

```
val command : String = ... // loaded from file somewhere
val processBuilder = Process(command)
val exitCode : Integer = processBuilder.!
```

the commands are (ran one by one):

```
/usr/bin/R --slave --silent --file=test.R argval1 >> out     
/usr/bin/R --slave --silent --file=test.R argval2 >> out     
/usr/bin/R --slave --silent --file=test.R argval3 >> out
```

These three shell commands above will work without exceptions but the `out` file is never created. Then the following final command fails:

```
awk 'n < $0 {n=$0}END{print n}' out > final
```

basically it picks the smallest element of file `out` and puts it in file `final`. The `awk` command will fail with the following error while running it in command line works fine:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
context is
 >>> ' <<< 
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those redirects are done by shell, and you are not running shell. maybe this would work better for you:

```
val processBuilder = Process("sh" :: "-c" :: command :: Nil)
```

Mind you, the process package let you redirect input and output directly, like this:

```
val processBuilder = Process(Seq("/usr/bin/R", "--slave", "--silent", "--file=test.R", "argval1")) #> new java.io.File("out")
```

Here I'm replacing a string with a `Seq` because that is generally a safer than letting Scala simply partition commands and arguments with spaces, since it doesn't recognize quotes.

Comment: The first part of your answer solves most of the problems. The only open point left is that the append ">>" is being interpreted as ">" redirect therefore the three first commands overwrite the previous instead of appending. Any ideas? then I will accept. :)

Comment: @GiovanniAzua That's not a Scala problem. The whole thing is being passed to shell, and I can't think of any reason for shell to do that. I suspect you are not executing the command line you think you are executing.

Answer (score 0):

The first option won't help if you need to run commands with |.